# Is java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(myfile.toPath()) better than new FileInputStream(file)?

Tags: java

I was using soanr to check my java code, and one issue shows that ,we should use java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(myfile.toPath()) instead of new FileInputStream(file). And the sonar description is :

> This method creates and uses a java.io.FileInputStream or java.io.FileOutputStream object. Unfortunately both of these classes implement a finalize method, which means that objects created will likely hang around until a full garbage collection occurs, which will leave excessive garbage on the heap for longer, and potentially much longer than expected. Java 7 introduced two ways to create streams for reading and writing files that do not have this concern. You should consider switching from these above classes to InputStream is = java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(myfile.toPath()); OutputStream os = java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(myfile.toPath());

My question is, is it right?

Comment: I'd be astonished. There's nothing about it being finalizer-free in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 6):

That is a dense statement. Thus, it might be worth to break it into smaller chunk. 
First thing first,

> This method creates and uses a java.io.FileInputStream or java.io.FileOutputStream object. Unfortunately both of these classes implement a finalize method

This is true and false. the function itself has been marked as deprecated since java 9. And, it has been removed 5 months ago. So, depending on java version you used. It probably still exists (assuming most people are still using java 8). See this [commit](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/0edbbc64393c) for more information.

> which means that objects created will likely hang around until a full garbage collection occurs, which will leave excessive garbage on the heap for longer, and potentially much longer than expected

Yeah, because, `finalize` function is invoked after GC. Then, most likely, the object would linger on the heap longer. See javadoc for `finalize` function [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29).

> Java 7 introduced two ways to create streams for reading and writing files that do not have this concern

True, I have checked the source code in openjdk repo. And, I don't see the implementation of classes that those two functions use implement the `finalize` method. See the repo [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk)